# Reverse CRT to compute modulus

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, computability

Very commonly we have a system as the one below, and if we know $a$ and $b$, then we can easily use CRT to solve for $c$.

$$
\begin{align}
x &\equiv a \pmod p \\
x &\equiv b \pmod q \\
x &\equiv c \pmod{pq} \\
% &gcd(p, q) = 1
\end{align}
$$

However, suppose we instead know $a$ and $c$, but not $b$.

What is the arithmetic way to solve this without directly doing reduction mod q?
Is this possible to compute using just $+,\ -,\ *,$ mod pq and mod p?

Clarification:  I am interested in finding **$b$** in addition to $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by "without directly doing reduction mod q?"

Comment: @BillDubuque I mean to arrive at the value of $b$ which is c mod q by only doing operations mod p or pq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know $c$ then you have
$$x=c+kpq$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ hence we also have
$$x\equiv c\mod{p}$$
$$x\equiv c\mod{q}$$
by taking the modulus of $p$ or $q$ on both sides of the above equality.

Comment: Right, and is there a way of calculating $b$ when I know everything else?  I vaguely remember there being a relation that does the 'reverse' of CRT using multiplication and addition mod p.

Comment: Do you mean the value of $c$ in the set of least residues $(\text{mod }q)$?

Comment: Yes the least element of c's congruence class

Comment: As far as I know, $a$ has no relationship to $b$ so if you want $b$ specifically then you would just have to use $$b=c-q\lfloor c/q\rfloor$$

Comment: Ok, this I what I was wondering.  I figured c might be related but that makes sense